# Why swagger return "Failed to load api definition"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is my code.
I'm trying to overload GET with 2 function :

- With one parameter
- With two parameter

I'm getting Swagger error "Failed to load API definition". Why ?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController] 
public class HospitalizedController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public string Get(string MedicID)
    {
        string jsonData;

        string connString = gsUtils.GetDbConnectionString();
        // dosomething
    
    }

    [HttpGet("")]
    public string Get(string MedicID, string PatientID)
    {
        string jsonData;

        string connString = gsUtils.GetDbConnectionString();
        
        //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Because the endpoint of the two methods is the same (/api/hospitalized). Maybe you can use: /api/hospitalized/{medicId} and /api/hospitalized/{medicId}/patients/{patientId} ?

Comment: Thank you: how to declare different endpoint ?

Comment: I've written the comment as an answer with an example for the Route attribute

Comment: have you tried `ActionName` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Failed to load API definition" occurs because the two methods are on the same `Route`.

You can specify a more specific route to distinguish them, like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController] 
public class HospitalizedController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{medicId}")]
    public string Get(string medicID)
    {
    
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{medicId}/patients/{patientId}")]
    public string Get(string medicID, string patientID)
    {

    }

}
```